# two php function in the same page conflict what can I change to?

Tags: php, web, authentication

I'm trying to protect page by making a member only area the code I use in this case is

```
<?php 
include 'dbc.php';
page_protect();


?>
```

there is no error by using this code and also it just working fine
but the problem is that whenever I place the below code in the same page
the problem will happen with the iPhone, only with this device but the rest still ok, like PCs, laptop and tablet (iPad) they are all no problem

But the iPhone the problem will be that you can access to the page after login but whenever you refresh it will redirect you to the login page and ask for login again.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['link'])){ 
    $link = 1; 
} else { 
    $link = $_GET['link']; 
}

if ($link == 1) {
echo "";
} elseif ($link == 23) {
echo "";
} else {
echo "";
} 
?>
```

There is no error show or anything.

my question is that is there anyway to protect the page because I need this to be member only area and the above code is very important and need to be in the page.

Thanks in advance.

here is the dbc.php sorry about that but I copied the whole script and placed here

```
<?php
/*************** PHP LOGIN SCRIPT V 2.3*********************
(c) Balakrishnan 2010. All Rights Reserved

Usage: This script can be used FREE of charge for any commercial or personal projects. Enjoy!

Limitations:
- This script cannot be sold.
- This script should have copyright notice intact. Dont remove it please...
- This script may not be provided for download except from its original site.

For further usage, please contact me.

/******************** MAIN SETTINGS - PHP LOGIN SCRIPT V2.1 **********************
Please complete wherever marked xxxxxxxxx

/************* MYSQL DATABASE SETTINGS *****************
1. Specify Database name in $dbname
2. MySQL host (localhost or remotehost)
3. MySQL user name with ALL previleges assigned.
4. MySQL password

Note: If you use cpanel, the name will be like account_database
*************************************************************/

define ("DB_HOST", "xxxxxx"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "xxxxxx"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","xxxxxxx"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","xxxxxx"); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

/* Registration Type (Automatic or Manual) 
 1 -> Automatic Registration (Users will receive activation code and they will be automatically approved after clicking activation link)
 0 -> Manual Approval (Users will not receive activation code and you will need to approve every user manually)
*/
$user_registration = 1;  // set 0 or 1

define("COOKIE_TIME_OUT", 10); //specify cookie timeout in days (default is 10 days)
define('SALT_LENGTH', 9); // salt for password

//define ("ADMIN_NAME", "admin"); // sp

/* Specify user levels */
define ("ADMIN_LEVEL", 5);
define ("USER_LEVEL", 1);
define ("GUEST_LEVEL", 0);



/*************** reCAPTCHA KEYS****************/
$publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


/**** PAGE PROTECT CODE  ********************************
This code protects pages to only logged in users. If users have not logged in then it will redirect to login page.
If you want to add a new page and want to login protect, COPY this from this to END marker.
Remember this code must be placed on very top of any html or php page.
********************************************************/

function page_protect() {
session_start();

global $db; 

/* Secure against Session Hijacking by checking user agent */
if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
        logout();
        exit;
    }
}

// before we allow sessions, we need to check authentication key - ckey and ctime stored in database

/* If session not set, check for cookies set by Remember me */
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) 
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
    /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

    $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['user_id']);
    $rs_ctime = mysql_query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    list($ckey,$ctime) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_ctime);
    // coookie expiry
    if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {

        logout();
        }
/* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.       
/* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

     if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['user_name']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
          session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.

          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_COOKIE['user_name'];
        /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */  
          list($user_level) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select user_level from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"));

          $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
          $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

       } else {
       logout();
       }

  } else {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
    }
}
}



function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    return $data;
}



function EncodeURL($url)
{
$new = strtolower(ereg_replace(' ','_',$url));
return($new);
}

function DecodeURL($url)
{
$new = ucwords(ereg_replace('_',' ',$url));
return($new);
}

function ChopStr($str, $len) 
{
    if (strlen($str) < $len)
        return $str;

    $str = substr($str,0,$len);
    if ($spc_pos = strrpos($str," "))
            $str = substr($str,0,$spc_pos);

    return $str . "...";
}   

function isEmail($email){
  return preg_match('/^\S+@[\w\d.-]{2,}\.[\w]{2,6}$/iU', $email) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function isUserID($username)
{
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{5,20}$/i', $username)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }  

function isURL($url) 
{
    if (preg_match('/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i', $url)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} 

function checkPwd($x,$y) 
{
if(empty($x) || empty($y) ) { return false; }
if (strlen($x) < 4 || strlen($y) < 4) { return false; }

if (strcmp($x,$y) != 0) {
 return false;
 } 
return true;
}

function GenPwd($length = 7)
{
  $password = "";
  $possible = "0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz"; //no vowels

  $i = 0; 

  while ($i < $length) { 


    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);


    if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
      $password .= $char;
      $i++;
    }

  }

  return $password;

}

function GenKey($length = 7)
{
  $password = "";
  $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

  $i = 0; 

  while ($i < $length) { 


    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);


    if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
      $password .= $char;
      $i++;
    }

  }

  return $password;

}


function logout()
{
global $db;
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
mysql_query("update `users` 
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
            where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
}           

/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

header("Location: login.php");
}

// Password and salt generation
function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null)     {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    else     {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
}

function checkAdmin() {

if($_SESSION['user_level'] == ADMIN_LEVEL) {
return 1;
} else { return 0 ;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: do you use sessions or cookies for holding the login? also the lower php is useless and is most likely not your problem

Comment: yes that is in the dbc.php is a sessions

Comment: but the problem is that whenever the below code place in the page the iPhone will not be logged in but when I take it off it will works fine

Comment: do you have session_start(); on the top of your login page & your members only page, before anything is outputted

Comment: no the session_start(); only in the login page,

the member only area is only protected by the very top code.

which is by default from the script owner.

Comment: unless `page_protect();` has session_start() in it then it will not hold the session

Comment: Yes it does have in the dbc.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170015/login-remember-me-functionality-stops-working-on-iphones-when-this-code-is-adde - You've posted the exact same code two times before - with varying problem descriptions. And you have been told that **it is not the relevant code part**. What makes you think you get useful answers by that?

Comment: @mario yeah i thought it was abit familiar

Comment: @mario the problem is that I'm sure there is a problem on the script that I have but I don't know where exactly

and now it just something I want to know from expert on php or who really experience this before

if still there won't be an answer for this so I will just move to the next step which I will create 20 files to remove the second php function (which I don't really want to do)

Comment: @Larence

so now it turn out to be that session_start(); in the login.php and also has it in the dbc.php

is that the problem there?

Comment: @Ali: We don't know where the problem is either, since you refuse to edit your original question and post anything else. And as it stands now, this is not a technical question for php experts; it's just a guessing game.

Comment: we will need to see dbc.php as the problem is most like there. todo with session_start or outputting content before the session was started. and all browser act differently, ever heard of internet explorer 6

Comment: @mario I'm not refuse to edit anything in here but I just don't know what to put. since lawrence was asking me about my session_start(); where it place so I answer it has on both pages on the login.php and also on the dbc.php

do you want me to place those script in my first post as well?

Comment: I have just post the dbc.php on the top post I hope this may tell something? if you want me to as well show the login.php I will include them on the top as well if required.

Comment: i believe its todo with cookies now, goto your site on your iphone and then follow this `http://rf.com/how-to/how-to-enable-cookies-on-the-iphone/` to enable cookies.

Comment: Lots and lots of debug opportunities! Everywhere you have an exit; or logout(); in your protect funtion, add an `print "protect error: user-agent.."` or something similar. Then say on which condition your iphone login fails. Also check if the session cookie is present at all (or it's just your iphone which has it disabled).

Comment: @Lawrence I'm testing with 4000 people who use iPhone, iPod touch that including iPhone 3G, iPhone 3Gs, and iPhone 4 including all generation of the iPod

all of my visitors facing the same problem that when they refresh the page it will send them back to the login page (it totally logout for them as well) that is why I'm super confuse and the weird thing if would say it because of Safari then why iPad still work

is like only happen to mobile version

Comment: then dont use this specific script that uses cookies or notify your users that they need cookies tobe enabled for session to hold login.

Comment: @Lawrence what can I do then? I just need to make protect page that can only access by people who logged in what would be the solution which script should I use? I'm just spent time on this for 24 hours and I can't find what would be the solution :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to your current protect script, ive made it without cookies:

```
<?php
//A basic login and session script I just whacked up 
session_start();

/**
 * cleanit cleans unwanted chars
 *
 * @param string $input
 * @return clean string containing only a-zA-Z0-9.,_ - 
 */
function cleanit($input){
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.,_ -]/s', '', $input);
}

/**
 * auth function called on each page you want protected
 *
 * @param $_SESSION['user_name'] $logged_in_user
 * @param $_SESSION['user_hash'] $hash
 * @param $_POST['user'] (when logging in) $username
 * @param $_POST['pass'] (when logging in) $password
 * @param [login|check|logout] function control $exe
 * @return $_SESSION gets set returns LOGGED_IN|ERROR:MULTI:USERS|ACCESS_DENIDE|ACCESS_TIMEOUT|ACCESS_LOGGED_OUT
 */
function auth($logged_in_user,$hash,$username,$password,$exe) {
    global $db;
    if ($exe=='login') {
        //LOGIN////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from users where username="'.cleanit(mysql_real_escape_string($username)).'" and password="'.cleanit(mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password))).'"',$db);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num=='1') {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['user_status']='LOGGED_IN';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['user_hash'] = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                $_SESSION['user_ip'] = cleanit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                $_SESSION['user_date'] = time();
                $_SESSION['user_level'] = cleanit($row['user_level']);
            }
            $result2 = mysql_query('REPLACE into users values ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_name']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password)).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_hash']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_ip']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_date']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_level']).'")',$db);
            $return = 'LOGGED_IN';
            return $return;
        }elseif($num >='2') {
            $result = mysql_query('DELETE from users where username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($username).'" and password="'.mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password)).'"');
            $error = 'ERROR:MULTI:USERS';
            return $error;
        }else {
            unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_hash']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_ip']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_date']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
            $_SESSION['user_status']=='';
            session_destroy();
            $return = 'ACCESS_DENIDE';
            return $return;
        }
        return $return;
    }

    if($exe=='check') {
        //CHECK////////////////////////////////////////////
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT hash,ip,user_date from users where username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($logged_in_user).'" and hash="'.mysql_real_escape_string($hash).'"',$db);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
            $rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $timeout = (time()-1800);
            if($rows[2]<=$timeout){auth("","","","","logout");
            return'ACCESS_TIMEOUT';
            }
            if($hash==$rows[0] && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']==$rows[1]) {
                $return = 'LOGGED_IN';
                mysql_query('UPDATE users set user_date="'.time().'"',$db);
                return $return;
            }else {
                session_regenerate_id();
                $return = 'ACCESS_DENIDE';
                return $return;
            }
        }else{
            session_regenerate_id();
            $return = $_SESSION['user_status'];
            return $return;
        }
    }
    if($exe=='logout') {
        //LOGOUT///////////////////////////////////////////
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_hash']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_ip']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_date']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_status']);
        session_destroy();
        session_regenerate_id();
        $return = 'ACCESS_LOGGED_OUT';
        return $return;
    }
    if($exe=='') {
        //BLANK////////////////////////////////////////////
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_hash']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_ip']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_date']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_status']);
        session_destroy();
        session_regenerate_id();
        $return = 'FUNCTION.ERROR:DO.MISSING';
        return $return;
    }
    return $return;
}


/*
SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hash` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_date` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_level` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `hash`, `ip`, `user_date`, `user_level`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', '6c7ca345f63f835cb353ff15bd6c5e052ec08e7a', 'f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6', '127.0.0.1', '1306757011', '1');

admin/admin1
*/


//Usage
/*--------------------------------*/
//login page
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['user']) && isset($_REQUEST['pass'])){
    $user=cleanit($_REQUEST['user']);
    $pass=cleanit($_REQUEST['pass']);
    $_SESSION['user_status'] = auth("","",$user,$pass,"login");
    header('members.php');
}else{
    //Show login form
}
/*--------------------------------*/



/*--------------------------------*/
//Members page
session_start();
//Checks login on each page request put this on all pages you want to protect
$_SESSION['session_status'] = @auth($_SESSION['user_name'],$_SESSION['user_hash'],"","","check");

if($_SESSION['session_status']=='LOGGED_IN'){
    //Logged in norm user
}elseif($_SESSION['session_status']=='LOGGED_IN' && $_SESSION['user_level']==1){
    //Logged in as admin
}else{
    //Logged out
}

/*--------------------------------*/
//Logout
if($_REQUEST['do']=='logout'){
    auth("","","","","logout");
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much just for my understanding this script should be use instead of the protect script is this mean I should replace this whole script on dbc.php? or just create a new file?

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment posted here for better formatting.

You have to read the [man pages on session_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) functions work! Doing so will save you time and aggravation.  Many here have given you hints on the possible source of your problem. For one, you cannot have  ANY output whatsoever before session_start().  For 2, [make sure you have error reporting turned on in your environnement](http://www.kreci.net/web-development/how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-php-script/).

```
if(!isset($_GET['link'])){ 
    $link = 1; 
} else { 
    $link = $_GET['link']; 
}

if ($link == 1) {
  echo "";
} elseif ($link == 23) {
  echo "";
} else {
  echo "";
```

}

This snippet at the top of your post will always make your script fail if you try to echo anything whatsoever.  Again, friendly advice, take 15 minutes of your time and read the manual. You will have access to much more valuable first-hand information on those aspects of your work than by posting here out of laziness to get a quick fix. Then again, I probably am not the first one to tell you this.

Comment: @stefgosselin I will going to visit the page you gave me and thank you very much for answering me the question about the echo part

Comment: PLeasure my friend. Give a man a fish you feed him for a day -> give him a fishing pole he will spend every weekend at the lake.

Comment: You got me so bad @stefgosselin :P I really like this quote and it just so true

to be honest I really enjoying doing this kind of stuff but the problem is that I'm not really expert yet would say I'm still newbie, but I'm going to programming course in this september so I hope I will be able to one day help people as your guys...

Comment: Hey. Hang in there. + 1 for your sportsmanship and good intentions. See if you can identify what is creating output in your script. Also, on a sidenote, this line:   $link = $_GET['link'];  is a security hole in your script because $_GET['link'] could be anything.

Comment: @stefgosselin I have like 10 channels in my website that I put in all those echo scripts which will look from the url address bar

example when click on page.php?link=1 then it will be this div class if page.php?link=2 it will be diff div class

Comment: @stefgosselin I just have a quick question for you I know it seem non sense

but when you said if I use the echo the script will fail

my concern is that is only fail on the iPhone but the rest of the devices is still working fine

is that echo only effect the mobile device possibly?

Comment: If you send any 'unbuffered'  regular output to the page before session_start,  session_start will return false ( fail ) and you will always get this warning message: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent . To prevent this either use output buffering ( see ob_start in php manual ) or make totally sure you never have output before session_start().

Comment: Maybe your script  only outputs the echos when connecting with iphone.

Comment: @stefgosselin thanks I'm going to see the ob_start in php manual now